# Use Google Analytics in Chrome packaged app?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I have an existing webapp that I'd like to package up as a chrome packaged app, but I'm getting the following error when trying to hit google analytics:

> Refused to load the image
>   'http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif...' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' blob:
>   filesystem: data: chrome-extension-resource:".

Adding `content_security_policy` to my `manifest.son` as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics) seems to be out of date and is giving me the error.

> There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
>   'content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy
>   packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.

What is the package app way to register a google analytics page view?

Answer (score 1):

The [apps documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy#what) says:

> Your Chrome App can only refer to scripts and objects within your app, with the exception of media files (apps can refer to video and audio outside the package). Chrome extensions will let you relax the default Content Security Policy; Chrome Apps won’t.

- Use [chrome-platform-analytics](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-platform-analytics) version of the GA script that supports apps
- Include the GA script in your app package, load it as a local script:

  ```html
  <script src="google-analytics-bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="mainwindow.js"></script>
  ```
- Add the necessary permissions in manifest.json:

  ```js
  "permissions": ["https://www.google-analytics.com/*"]
  ```
- Initialize it:

  ```js
  service = analytics.getService('my_app');
  service.getConfig().addCallback(function(config) {
      console.log(config.isTrackingPermitted());
      config.setTrackingPermitted(true);
  });

  // Get a Tracker using your Google Analytics app Tracking ID.
  tracker = service.getTracker('UA-XXXXX-X');

  // Record an "appView" each time the user launches your app or goes to a new
  // screen within the app.
  tracker.sendAppView('MainView');
  ```

The code is quoted from [Google analytics app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/analytics) in the official app samples [repository on github](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/).

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to set up a new google analytics property, or can I use the same one I use for the web? Is an app view the same thing as a page view? And what is 'my_app' in the call to getService referring to?

Comment: Please use the documentation/wiki of chrome-platform-analytics.